# Image in my web app doesn't show up but added properly

Tags: html, css

Here is my project structure:

[image]

I have a problem with displaying this `wallpaper.jpg`

This is my code:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('images/wallpaper.jpg');
}
```

Comment: In which file do you define your css code which you provided in your question?

Comment: in style.css...

Comment: have you tried `background-image: url('../../../images/wallpaper.jpg');`?

Comment: doesn't work: `2020-07-17T22:46:18.896797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/wallpaper.jpg" host=jawegiel-web.herokuapp.com request_id=e5b2b611-0abd-4efe-bd40-83d3dd55c3ab fwd="89.64.26.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=355 protocol=https`

Comment: Don't believe you used the relative path properly or updated your heroku stack after the change.  The error `at=info method=GET path="/images/wallpaper.jpg"` suggests it still had your old deployment and path.

Comment: I did this deployment as always, I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I need to move my images folder into static folder.